# Вывод информации из базы данных в ListBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, linq

Есть бд MSSQL в ней таблица Users, в ней поля Photo и UserName. В поле Photo хранятся фотографии формата jpeg(да, я знаю что это плохая идея, но у меня такое тз). В программе есть ListBox с шаблоном данных(да, я знаю что сверстал хреново и я знаю что хранить кнопки в каждом item'е плохая затея, но у меня опять же такое тз). Итак вопрос такой: как мне загрузить данные из таблицы в ListBox средствами linq?

Вот так я получаю данные из таблицы:

```
UsersEntities bs = new UsersEntities();
var data = from User in bs.User
           select User;
```

Вот код XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,40,10,10">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Source ="{Binding Photo}"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="3"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="20"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Content="Window1" FontSize="18" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3,10" Background="Aqua"/>
                    <Button Content="Window2" FontSize="18" Grid.Column="2" Margin="3,10" Background="Aqua"/>
                    <Button Content="Window3" FontSize="18" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3,10" Background="Aqua"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

P.S Я бьюсь с этой ерундой 2 дня. Буду бесконечно благодарен тому кто подскажет как такое осуществить. Задавайте любые вопросы если что то непонятно.

Comment: А в чем проблема-то собственно? Вам понадобится конвертер `jpg byte[]` в `ImageSource` и установить вашему `ListBox` свойство `ItemsSource`

Comment: Чувак, я буду молиться ежедневно за весь твой род до 100000000 поколения!!! Ты написал все что нужно было и все что я искал приблизительно 30 часов!!! Славься великий Андрей NOP!!!